# Using an adapter on a 220 outlet

Tags: adapter

I have a clothes washer that runs on a normal 110 plug.

I have an available a 220 4 prong plug in the wall.  It has it's own breaker slot and is currently unused.

The washer manufactures makes an adapter NEMA 14-30/2x5-15 which has 3 prongs and provides 2 x 110 outlets.

I want to put the 3 prong adapter into the 4 prong 220 outlet and use just one of the 110 outlets to run the washer.

Will that work?

Comment: Do you not have a 120V circuit to your laundry room?

Answer (score 2):

It will work, but it is not a good idea. The problem is most washers are designed for a 15A or 20A circuit. A typical 4 wire dryer circuit will be 30A. You could have a motor problem where a 20A breaker would trip fairly quickly but a 30A breaker would not, leading to damage that would be prevented on the proper circuit.

The best solution, in terms of functionality (but not necessarily cost) is to:

- Replace the double 30A breaker with a double 20A breaker.
- Replace the 4-wire dryer receptacle with a duplex 120V 20A receptacle.
- Remove the tab connecting the two *hot* screws. Do **not** remove the tab connecting the two neutral terminals.
- Hot wires go to the two hot screws.
- Neutral wire goes to one of the two neutral screws.
- Ground wire goes to the ground screw.

Poof. You now have a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit (MWBC).

Note, however, that you will very likely (depends on location) need GFCI protection. That can be done with a GFCI breaker. It can be done other ways, so if that is not an option then provide more details and ask another question.

Comment: If they replace the breaker with a 20 amp 240v then would it be safer? I guess at that point why not just convert it to a 120v line and replace the receptacle though.

Comment: Correct. the right thing to do is 20a breaker and split duplex aka MWBC.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that's what mana is doing.  Just setting it up as MWBC (which actually creates a GFCI problem though, as laundry room outlets need GFCI protection).

Answer (score 2):

There are many adapters that dangerously do not provide overcurrent protection. I can't speak for the adapter you are looking at but Southwire makes a gas range adapter that has 15A protection. https://amzn.to/3q7Z5PA I'm not sure it would handle motor inrush well, but at $12 it wouldn't be a big investment lost.

Comment: Nice, didn't know a fused one exists!   But wow ... the Amazon listing says that an FAQ they get is whether this adapter converts the outlet to gas.  Seriously.

Comment: *That* item from Amazon is actually safe.  It is made by Southwire, a company used to supplying approved stuff, and it's UL listed, and it's sold by Amazon Proper, not Amazon Marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

### That's alright *if the adapter is UL Listed*.

Don't buy random junk on Amazon.  CE and CCC are junk marks typically found in dangerous cheapo crud from you-know-where.

A UL listed adapter will have fuse protection of 15A or 20A to protect the outlets.  *The fuse is not necessarily replaceable*.  If it has 2 outlets total, the fuse will match the sockets (15A socket = 15A fuse).  If it has 4 sockets total, you might get a 20A fuse with 15A sockets.  You probably want a 20A fuse if you have your choice.

Comment: This particular item has a fuse that is *not* replaceable. I have a hunch that is not to save money (fuse holders don't cost much) but that UL **required** it to avoid abuse by someone replace the 15A fuse with a larger fuse.